# disable comments if array exists

Tags: functions, comments, conditional-tags

This is the code which is registering the function for **rewrite_endpoints()**:

```
function wpa121567_rewrite_endpoints(){

add_rewrite_endpoint( 'comments', EP_PERMALINK );

add_rewrite_endpoint( 'stats', EP_PERMALINK );

}

add_action( 'init', 'wpa121567_rewrite_endpoints' );
```

**NOTE** 
I don't know if this matters but I will write it.

I have **single-CPT.php** which is calling  **/inc/post-format/single-CPT.php** like this:

```
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<?php 

get_template_part( 'inc/post-format/single-debate'); 
    ...
```

This is the code which is checking if **array key exists**, which is  inside my **/inc/post-format/single-cpt.php**:

```
?php
if( array_key_exists( 'comments', $wp_query->query_vars ) ){
 the_field('comments_section'); 

} elseif( array_key_exists( 'stats', $wp_query->query_vars ) ) {

 the_field('stats_section'); 
 } else {
// the request is for the main post
 }
  ?>
```

This is my **comments.php** :

```
     <div id="comments" class="comments-area">
<?php
// If CPT and not logged in, display a message:
if ( 'debate' == get_post_type() && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
echo '<p class="must-log-in" style="padding-left:20px; font-size:20px;">You must be logged in to post a comment.' . '</p>';

echo do_shortcode("[upme_login]");

 }
?>
    <?php if ( have_comments() ) : ?>
        <h3 class="comments-title">

            <?php
                printf( _n('%d comment', '%d comments', get_comments_number(), 'outbox' ),
                    number_format_i18n( get_comments_number() ) );
            ?>
        </h3>




        <ol class="commentlist">

            <?php
                wp_list_comments( array( 'callback' => 'outbox_comment' ) );
            ?>
        </ol><!-- .commentlist -->

        <?php if ( get_comment_pages_count() > 1 && get_option( 'page_comments' ) ) : // are there comments to navigate through? If so, show navigation ?>
        <nav role="navigation" id="comment-nav-below" class="site-navigation comment-navigation clearfix">
            <div class="nav-previous"><i class="icon-left-open-1"></i>&nbsp;<?php echo get_previous_comments_link( __( 'Older Comments', 'outbox' ) ); ?></div>
            <div class="nav-next"><?php echo get_next_comments_link( __( 'Newer Comments', 'outbox' ) ); ?>&nbsp;<i class="icon-right-open-1"></i></div>
        </nav><!-- #comment-nav-below .site-navigation .comment-navigation -->
        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php endif; // have_comments() ?>

    <?php
        // If comments are closed and there are comments, let's leave a little note, shall we?
        if ( ! comments_open() && '0' != get_comments_number() && post_type_supports( get_post_type(), 'comments' ) ) :
    ?>
        <p class="nocomments"><?php _e( 'Comments are closed.', 'outbox' ); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>

   <?php
 // Don't output the comment form if CPT and user isn't logged in
if ( 'debate' != get_post_type() || is_user_logged_in() ) {
 comment_form();
}

?>

</div><!-- #comments .comments-area -->
<?php } ?>
```

This is how the comments template is included  inside my **single-CPT.php** :

```
if ( comments_open()  )

comments_template( '', true );
```

I want to disable comments if `if( array_key_exists( 'comments', $wp_query->query_vars ) ){`

How can I do this?

Comment: Where is `comments_template()` (the function that actually includes `comments.php` in the template) being called? Is it being called by `the_field( 'comments_section' )`?

Comment: `comments_template()` is called inside `single-CPT.php`. I've updated my question with the code which is calling it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're properly using [`comment_form()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form) to output the comment reply form:

```
if( ! array_key_exists( 'comments', $wp_query->query_vars ) ) {
    // Output the comment form
    comment_form();
}
```

### Edit

Based on your `comments.php` code:

```
// If the user isn't logged in, don't display comment form
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    global $wp_query;
    // If the post type isn't 'debate',
    // Or if the 'comments' array key exists in the query
    // Display the comment form
    if ( 'debate' != get_post_type() || ! array_key_exists( 'comments', $wp_query->query_vars ) ) {
        comment_form();
    }
}
```

I'm taking a complete stab in the dark here, because it's not entirely clear how your comments template is being included in your template.

### Edit 2

I don't think this will work as intended:

```
if ( comments_open()  )

comments_template( '', true );
```

See that extra line break? Without curly braces around your conditional, the two lines aren't related. You need to do one of the following:

```
if ( comments_open() )
    comments_template( '', true );
```

or, better yet:

```
if ( comments_open() ) {
    comments_template( '', true );
}
```

Comment: I've tried this but is not working properly. After I add this code, inside my single post I see 2 comment forms and if I enter on my mywebsite/single-post/comments I see just one.Your code seems to work but It's adding an extra comment form inisde my main post. I've updated my question with how I've registered that array key.

Comment: You need to update your question with your **actual template code that outputs the comment form**. Otherwise, specific help is impossible.

Comment: I've updated my question with the code from my **comments.php**

Comment: Your `comments.php` markup does not include the `array_key_exists()` conditional. Where have you tried to place it?

Comment: The `array_key_exists()` are inside my single-CPT.php

Comment: Please **edit your question** to include **all relevant code**, in context.

Comment: I've edited, I've added all the relevant code. I hope this is more clear.

Comment: See updated answer. I've taken a stab at what I think you're after.

Comment: I've updated my question with how the comments template is included.

Comment: Just tried it, and now comment form is disabled inside my main **single-post** and enabled inside my **single-post/comments**. I want it to be the other way around, enabled on **single-post** and disabled on **single-post/comments**

Comment: I inadvertently left of the `!` in the `array_key_exists()` conditional.