# strange conditional tag behaviour

Tags: custom-post-types, conditional-tags, comment-form

I have this code  inside my comments.php :

```
<?php
 // If CPT and not logged in, display a message:
 if ( 'CPT' == get_post_type() && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
 echo '<p class="must-log-in" style="padding-left:20px; font-size:20px;">You must be logged in to post a comment.' . '</p>';

 echo do_shortcode("[upme_login]");

 }
 ?>
```

and this code :

```
   <?php
 // Don't output the comment form if CPT and user isn't logged in

  if ( 'CPT' != get_post_type() || ! array_key_exists( 'comments', $wp_query->query_vars ) ) {

 comment_form();
 }

 ?>
```

When the user is not logged in it should display a message like  **You must be logged in....** which is doing, **but** I see the comment form also which normally I shouldn't see it.

If I remove this `|| ! array_key_exists( 'comments', $wp_query->query_vars )` everything is working as expected.

How can I do  to make it visible if the user is logged in?

What is wrong?

Comment: Does `var_dump( $wp_query->query_vars );` around there shows expected results? Might be that global is not accessible there.

Comment: That is showing expected results, but as I said it's displaying the comment form if the user is not logged in which normally shouldn't display it and if I get rid of `|| ! array_key_exists( 'comments', $wp_query->query_vars )` is working but I don't want this

Comment: But there is no check for user logged in around `comment_form()` call in your example?..

Comment: No, it isn't any check for logged in user... but is in the first code

Comment: How would second code know what is going on in first code?

Comment: I've tried this, but still not working as expected, I've updated my question with what I've tried. Please take a look...

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is the third iteration/variation of the same question. In the future, please **edit your original question** to clarify what you need, rather than asking multiple questions with only minor variations.

Comment: Note: [original question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/124300/disable-comments-if-array-exists), [first variation](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/124304/changing-default-comment-form-arguments), [second variation](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/124320/hide-approved-comments-on-specifc-post-from-cpt). And now this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first version of your code, you don't check if user is logged in.

In the second attempt your logic is wrong, I guess.

So your code should look like so:

```
<?php
    // If CPT and not logged in, display a message:
    if ( 'CPT' == get_post_type() && !is_user_logged_in() ) {
        echo '<p class="must-log-in" style="padding-left:20px; font-size:20px;">You must be logged in to post a comment.' . '</p>';
        echo do_shortcode('[upme_login]');
    }
?>

...

<?php
    if ( 'CPT' != get_post_type() || (is_user_logged_in() && array_key_exists( 'comments', $wp_query->query_vars )) ) {
        comment_form();
    }
?>
```

This code will:

- Show message "You must be ..." if user is not logged in and is viewing CPT.
- Show no such message on other post types.
- Show comment form on CPT only if user is logged in.
- Show comment form on other post types always.